# favicon has unwanted white border around it in Safari on macOS

Tags: html, css, web, favicon

I am having an issue with my favicon on safari for macOS. For all other browsers it works fine, but in safari it has a white border around it:

[image]

I have supplied three different sizes for this icon and my code is as follows:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon-180x180.png" sizes="180x180" />
```

What am I doing wrong here? (Note I have cleared the favicon cache in Safari each time I test this)

Comment: Hi, this similar questions suggests it may be due to how dark your icon is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59233531/